# Separate variables from data table and create new data table

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I want to transform this table (*CSp_raw*)

| CSp | nb |
| --- | --- |
| P12-P13 | 41671 |
| P12-P13,P128-P129 | 5 |
| P12-P13,P128-P129,P73-P74 | 6 |
| P12-P13,P41-P42 | 3 |
| P12-P13,P41-P42,P128-P129,P73-P74 | 2 |
| P12-P13,P41-P42,P73-P74 | 4 |
| P12-P13,P73-P74 | 255 |
| P128-P129 | 18 |
| P128-P129,P73-P74 | 23 |
| P41-P42 | 58 |
| P41-P42,P128-P129 | 1 |
| P41-P42,P128-P129,P73-P74 | 12 |
| P41-P42,P73-P74 | 26 |
| P6-P7 | 1 |
| P73-P74 | 608 |

into this table (*CSp_table*):

| P12-P13 | P128-P129 | P73-P74 | P41-P42 | P6-P7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 41946 | 67 | 936 | 106 | 1 |

I use this code:

```
tmp_colname <- str_c(CSp_raw$CSp, collapse = ',') %>% 
  str_split(pattern = ',')

CSp_table <- lapply(tmp_colname, function(p){
  list(data.frame(p[1], p[2], p[3], p[4], p[5]))
})

CSp_table <- data.frame(CSp_table) %>% 
  rename('P12-P13' = 'p.1.', 'P128-P129' = 'p.2.', 'P73-P74' = 'p.3.', 'P41-P42' = 'p.4.', 'P6-P7' = 'p.5.')

CSp_tmp <- CSp_raw %>% 
  filter(str_detect(CSp, 'P12-P13')) # repeat for each variables

CSp_table[,'P12-P13'] <- sum(CSp_tmp$nb) # repeat for each variables
```

I have many data *CSp_raw* where *CSp_raw$CSp* change so i need a more efficient & reproductible code.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use data.table as follow:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(CSp_raw)

tab = CSp_raw[, .(grp=unlist(strsplit(CSp, ",", FALSE))), by=nb][, .(sm=sum(nb)), by=grp]

         grp    sm
1:   P12-P13 41946
2: P128-P129    67
3:   P73-P74   936
4:   P41-P42   106
5:     P6-P7     1
```

and if you prefer the transposed table (like in your request), you can simply call the function `transpose` on the table created.

```
CSp_table = transpose(tab, make.names=TRUE)

   P12-P13 P128-P129 P73-P74 P41-P42 P6-P7
1:   41946        67     936     106     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Split into new rows, then group by sum:

```
library(data.table)
d[, rn := .I
  ][,.(grp = unlist(tstrsplit(CSp, ",", fixed = TRUE))), by = .(rn, nb)
    ][, .(mySum = sum(nb)), by = .(grp)]
#          grp mySum
# 1:   P12-P13 41946
# 2: P128-P129    67
# 3:   P73-P74   936
# 4:   P41-P42   106
# 5:     P6-P7     1
```

Or using tidyr:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
d %>% 
  separate_longer_delim(CSp, ",") %>% 
  group_by(CSp) %>% 
  summarise(mySum = sum(nb))
#   CSp       mySum
#   <chr>     <int>
# 1 P12-P13   41946
# 2 P128-P129    67
# 3 P41-P42     106
# 4 P6-P7         1
# 5 P73-P74     936
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use `splitstackshape::cSplit_e` to transform this kind of "multiple choice" columns into binary columns.

```r
splitstackshape::cSplit_e(dt,
                          "CSp",
                          sep = ",",
                          mode = "binary",
                          type = "character", 
                          fill = 0, 
                          drop = TRUE
                          ) %>% 
rename_with(~str_remove(.x,"^CSp_")) %>% 
  summarise(across(`P12-P13`:`P73-P74`, ~sum(nb[.x == 1], na.rm = TRUE) ) ) 
#>   P12-P13 P128-P129 P41-P42 P6-P7 P73-P74
#> 1   41946        67     106     1     936
```

#### Data

```r
dt <- read.table(text = "CSp    nb
P12-P13 41671
P12-P13,P128-P129   5
P12-P13,P128-P129,P73-P74   6
P12-P13,P41-P42 3
P12-P13,P41-P42,P128-P129,P73-P74   2
P12-P13,P41-P42,P73-P74 4
P12-P13,P73-P74 255
P128-P129   18
P128-P129,P73-P74   23
P41-P42 58
P41-P42,P128-P129   1
P41-P42,P128-P129,P73-P74   12
P41-P42,P73-P74 26
P6-P7   1
P73-P74 608", h = TRUE)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>